# If there is an $x$ such that $(2x_n)$ converges, does this imply that $(x_n)$ is also convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am toying around with the definition of convergence of sequences. Ans I asked myself the following question:

Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence such that there is an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$ there is an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x-2x_n|
<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

In other words, the sequence $(2x_n)$ converges to $x$.

I feel that $(x_n)$ converges to a real number $y\in\mathbb{R}$, but I am unable to prove this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: @hardmath: I made an error in the formulation. See inprovement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x/2$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be an index such that $|x-2x_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.  Then $|x/2 - x_n| < \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$.  So $(x_n)$ converges to $x/2$.

Answer (score 2):

If
$|x-2x_n|
<\epsilon
$,
then
$|x/2-x_n|
<\epsilon/2
$
so
$x_n$ converges to
$x/2$.